# Material Editor: Generate mask from color ID texture

Tags: texturing, node-editor, masking

I'm trying to work out a way to generate a mask based on a color ID texture in the material editor (not the compositor). What I'm trying to achieve is have a node group I can re-use which has two parameters, the first parameter is the color ID texture and the second parameter is the color from the texture I want to generate a mask from.

I've included an illustration:
[image]

I got it working for some colors (such as red, green, or blue) but it didn't work in all cases, I also had a problem where the mask would show up properly when previewing it through an emissive shader but wouldn't show up when viewed through a normal diffuse shader.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: so do you need to improve that IDtoMASK node to work with all colors ?

Comment: Exactly, it has to work with any input color, basically I need it to extract the selected input color from the color ID texture and output a grayscale mask. There's a similar node in Substance Designer but I don't remember what it's called.

Comment: see the answer and adjest its output to get gray scale , i get some work to do now

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two independent node groups for creating a mask based on a color and a texture :

material setup :

[image]

the **first** node group outputs **boolean** 1/0  ( all comparisions are "less than "):

[image]

the **second** node group outputs **grayscale** :

[image]

adjust the sensitivity/clipping to get a good result "sensitivity is added to overcome  errors due to rounding the numbers"

Comment: @Spiderhund use the eyedropper to pick the exact color from the uv/Image editor

Comment: Thank you for a quick response! It works much better than what I had before, I noticed that it selects multiple colors though, for example if I choose the orange color it actually selects the blue color instead and if I choose the blue color it selects both the blue and the cyan color.

Comment: @Chebhou can this be done without separating colors with something like vector math?

Comment: Alright if I add an inverted between the "Absolute" node and the "Greater Than" node I can isolate the exact color I want using the sensitivity slider. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Spiderhund thanks for the correction, i have flipped the comparision now "see the edit" and have added a group node that outputs gray scale

Comment: @Chebhou Thank you! This is exactly what I needed!

Comment: @Bithur yes some steps can be done with vector math but there is no comparison node for vectors

Comment: Can you update your first picture, it only shows one node group while the rest of your question mentions two.

Comment: @David it's not supposed two the two at the same time  because they do the same work

Comment: So you are showing two different options. right?

Comment: 2 different options for IDtoMASK node group (screenshots with greenish background) with the same overall connections (1st screenshot)

Comment: @David exactly,  sorry for the unclear comment

Answer (score 1):

Here is a little osl script.
In the shader editor import the script node and open the osl file.
Just plug the ID map in the map color and the color that yo want to pick in to the rgb color.

Enable Open Shading Language
[image]

Copy&paste this script into Text Editor ...

```
//instagram https://www.instagram.com/renderthing
//sketchfab https://sketchfab.com/renderthing

shader mySwitch(

color map = color(0,0,1), 
color rgb = color(0,0,1),
float threshold = 0.005,
output color finely = 0.5



)
{

//first

color MAX = map + (threshold /2);
color MIN = map - (threshold /2);


if ( (MIN[0] <= rgb[0]) && (MAX[0] >= rgb[0]) && (MIN[1] <= rgb[1]) && (MAX[1] >= rgb[1]) && 
(MIN[1] <= rgb[1]) && (MAX[1] >= rgb[1]) 



){
    finely = color(1,1,1);
}
else {
    finely = color(0,0,0);
}










}
```

... and use as *Internal* (or save in some text app as .osl file and use as *External*).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

wow, i used an other method but mine is so small i'm ashamed of how simple it is :), but i have tested it with different shades of some colors like dark blue and light blue and it worked well.
anyways its like this[image: ID map mask node]