# How to set Opacity Maps with colored tga textures?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, transparency

I've purchased a 3D model car with some good textures, I was doing good until I came trying to apply the opacity maps.
Usually I set the opacity maps with textures in black and white, but this time the textures have some weird colors and I'm not sure how to set these Opacity maps in cycles.

Here are some of the Opacity Maps included in the file:
[image: multiple color alpha texture map]
[image: multiple color alpha texture map]

Any ideas? I'm using Blender v2.79 with Cycles engine

Comment: Check here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/90064/using-an-rgb-map-to-assign-various-shaders-in-a-material/90065#90065

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like the alpha is in the blue channel of those images.
[image: blue channel of image in cycles]

To use it in cycles just add a *[Seperate RGB](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/nodes/types/converter/combine_separate.html)* node in between the image and where you normally would plug the alpha in (probably the *Fac* in a mix node).

---

I'm guessing the other colors are kind of an id map (just other parts of the texture segregated) so you can apply different shaders to different parts. And example is the "corvete" sticker on the right side. If you wanted to make the letters less shiny then the rest of the sticker, then you have a texture to use for that.

[image: id map image]

This is really nothing more then putting mutipal black and white texture maps into one color image.

Comment: Seems right to me! Thank you very much for your help! :)