# How to emit light from texture?

Tags: texturing, materials, light

I have made a building and texture for it. I want to make this building for a night scene, which means that I want it to glow or emit light from the window to look realistic. Is it possible to make it glow or emit light from the texture?

[image]

#### Texture Building

[image: screenshot of texture building]

#### Night Render view

[image: dark screenshot with paint lines indicating the desired glow result]

#### Nodes

[image: screenshot of currently used nodes]

What extra nodes should I add to give a light or emission glow from the window?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/90064/using-an-rgb-map-to-assign-various-shaders-in-a-material

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos its not glowing.Is there any node like photoshop eye dropper click and separate glow for that shade.

Comment: select all the windows and assign them an Emission node, and in the Compositing, give this layer a glow effect

Comment: @moonboots i think you did not get what i mean. The building has a single texture how the windows can be selected separately.

Comment: @p2or but i have texture not just plane material

Answer (score 0):

Try to bake the building texture to an image and then create an alpha map. Make the window areas white filling the white color in photoshop(precisely) and everything else being dark black...

then load this image as texture in (cycles)Node editor . Mix two shaderes

DIFFUSE -----+-----EMISSION And connect the alpha map to the factor input.. I hope this will help...

there may be other ways to do this, I told you the easiest as it seems to me.

(Even I am learning Blender, so there may be some better solution to it, but I am willing to help with how much I have to share.)

Good luck

Answer (score -2):

Just tweaking with the simple nodes i got this result and satisfied what i need

[image]

With the RGB-BW and color ramp i mix it and with emission.

Comment: In your current setup, all the surface that is not emitting is staying black (shadeless). Put a Diffuse Node with the texture into the middle input of the Mix Shader node to have it back.

Comment: @NicolaSap you mean between coloramp and mix shader i have to insert a diffuse node

Comment: no, in the green empty spot in the Mix shader