# How do I apply complex texture in Blender?

Tags: texturing, materials

I have basic skill for 3D.

So I have an .obj file and the texture assets extracted from the game called Mobile Legends.

I want to import the model but the original model texture or shading is too complex for me, but I want to know how to make texture or shading like this.

[Here is the original model.](https://youtu.be/wwpM7FcQ8p4)

[image]

[image]

As you can see the model is very complex, so I want to ask your help.

**How to make the animated texture or material (I don't know either texture or material that animates in it) like on her arms and her legs?**

I wonder if it is uses a mask. I have the material but I have no idea how to make it happen. I search on google, I got no answer. So I ask here.

If you want to take a look the texture and material, here it is:

[image]

[image]

[image]

And I don't know which the mask material is on that asset list.

If you want to take a look the .obj [use this link](https://www.mediafire.com/file/0ifq8t784k2nma3/Selena.rar/file)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to properly hook up various maps types together in cycles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/55232/how-to-properly-hook-up-various-maps-types-together-in-cycles)

Comment: no, basically my question is a different thing.

Comment: If you believe your question is different then please explain *how* it is different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i built you a setup how this works in blender. for better understanding you should inform yourself about UV-Coordinates, and Normals maps.

For animating the glow effect of the armour you could animate the marked green multiply.
For animating the glowing helmet you could animate it with the mapping node, for example with rotation. But this depends what kind of effect you want to achiev.

What i didnt took into account is the color id map/mask texture so you could controll the glowing areas individualy. To achiev that you could implement this solution: [Using an RGB map to assign various shaders in a material](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/90064/using-an-rgb-map-to-assign-various-shaders-in-a-material)

Body-Material:
[image]

Helmet-Material:
[image]

if you have any further questions, feel free to ask.

Comment: and i also ignored the _s texture. dont know what its ment to be. maby Subsurface Color (doesnt make sense either)? Anyone got an idea?

Comment: I'm so so sorry, I still don't know how to animate it. Maybe u can tell it with video, it would be great. but thx for the answer at least now I know some nodes :)

Comment: the tricky part was the material not knowing how the nodeeditor works, so i think your good to go because now its realy straight foreward setting keyframes with "i" while howering over the value (ex.: the green multiply) then moving the timestamp and repeating setting keyframes. here is a tutorial about Keyframes: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Wb_ftxZ37o  this works also in the node editor

Comment: other ways to animate materials: 1 Drivers, 2 Animation Nodes; but i think for this its better to just set some keyframes

Comment: I dit master, can I ask 1 question more. I confused how to make it looped :)

Comment: If you did it with keyframes, just go to "Dope Sheet" copy then whith "shift + d" and drag them with "g", so that it loops.

Comment: Oke master case closed master. Thx for sharing this :)