# Mask by Colour with Nodes

Tags: node-editor, color

Is it possible to mask by colour with nodes? Say for instance I use the colour output of a procedural noise. How could I extract the "red" noise from the RGB noise as a greyscale isolated map? So that I could further use that as a multiply/subtract noise mask.

In Terragen we have nodes such as Red to Scalar, Green to Scalar, and Blue to Scalar, but I can't find a similar node in Blender.

Update: I am leaving this question up, and not deleting it because of its relevance to another topic, because it is not relevant by title in that people may not even know what a "RGB Map" is. There is a reason I didn't find it, or the related questions didn't bring it up initially.

Further reading: [Using an RGB map to assign various shaders in a material](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/90064/using-an-rgb-map-to-assign-various-shaders-in-a-material)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use the separate RGB node like this:

[image]

Comment: Oh thank you. Probably should have searched more within Blender than relying on Google. OT: Boy, do a lot of irrelevant tutorials pop up filling search results.

Comment: you are welcome