# Map texture to white part of other texture

Tags: shaders

I have simple black and white texture, how would i map another texture on top of it such that that the texture is on white parts and not on black part

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/90064/using-an-rgb-map-to-assign-various-shaders-in-a-material/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46424/add-a-transparent-image-on-top-of-a-material

Answer (score 1):

### Use a Math node set to *Multiply* (Or a MixRGB).

If both textures are black & white, this should work.

All the black parts of both will stay black, and where black & white overlap, it will become black.

Answer (score 0):

I used mix shader, with factor set to the value of the image i want to overlay on top of