# How can I use a Noise Texture and Bump node for only specific portions of a model with an Image Texture?

Tags: texturing, materials, shader-nodes

I'm trying to get more familiar with the Shader Editor. I would like to create a realistic steel texture on the character's claw, shoulder piece, etc.. I have an Image Texture I'm using connected to the Metallic part of the Principled BDSF which looks good. The Metallic map is painted so only the metal portions of the model are metallic. But I would also like to combine it with a Noise Texture and a Bump node. How may I go about this?

Perhaps I could use a Mix Shader with 2 Principled BDSF's attached to it? I tried that and it didn't seem to work.

Thank you so much!!!

[image]
[image]

Comment: If you already have a mask texture for the metallic parts and would like to apply bump only there you can use the same texture as mask for the bump. Use a *Mix Texture* node over a *Mix Shader* , it is preferable to mix at texture level whenever possible

Comment: Would you be able to attach an image of what that would look like in the Shader Editor?

Comment: Here's a roughly the same use case https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/90064/using-an-rgb-map-to-assign-various-shaders-in-a-material

Comment: I've tried to apply similarly what they're doing in that post but it only made me more confused. I should iterate that I am a complete beginner with the Node Editor. Can someone please post a new image from them creating a new set up in the Shader Editor for my situation? Thank you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use your metallic image texture mask to mask the bump map input, much like you masked metallic parts.

Assuming you mask is a black and white image, plug its *Color* output into a *Color Mix Node* into the *Factor* socket.

Plug the *Color Mix Node* result into the *Bump* node *Height* socket. From then on use whatever you like as bum maps on both zones.

Assuming you want the non metallic parts without roughness use a solid color. On the other socket use your *Noise* texture.

[image]

This is the result using [this silhouette](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Dancer_silhouette_4,_1924.svg) as mask[image]